# Laravel- filter result by several parameters

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I want filter a table with several parameters. which I get from a form. it is the index function of the controller where i want to do these things. How can pass these form values to result, how to use laravel collection to apply filter to result. Sorry for a messy question and being silly.

Here is my **controller code**

```
        $keyword = Input::get('keyword');
        $mfs_id = Input::get('mfs_id');
        $tps_id = Input::get('tps_id');
        $date_start = Input::get('date_start');
        $date_end = Input::get('date_end');
        //values passed to view
        $sales = Sale::paginate(10);
        $total = Sale::sums('total_online_sale', 'discount', 'delivery_cost','sales_vat');
        $mfs = Mf::lists('mfs_name', 'id');
        $tps = Tp::lists('tps_name','id');

        // load the view and pass the values
        return View::make('sales.index')
                        ->with('sales', $sales)
                        ->with('total',$total)
                        ->with('mfs',$mfs)
                        ->with('tps',$tps);
```

In view file I am using a form to get `$keyword, $mfs_id, $tps_id, $date_start, $date_end`

**view code**

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('sales.index', array('keyword' => $keyword, 'mfs_id' => $mfs_id, 'tps_id' => $tps_id, 'date_start' => $date_start, 'date_end' => $date_end)))) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries

```
$users = DB::table('users')->where('start', '>', $date_start)
    ->where('end', '<=', $date_end)
```

Or with model:

```
$users = Users::where('start', '>=', $date_start)
    ->where('end', '<=', $date_end)
```

Replace users with your model and add all the parameters in chainging them.